# Use environment variables in terminator config

Tags: environment-variables, command, gnome-terminator

I want to launch terminator with multiple terminals with some starting on a different directory. The directories could change based on the `$USER` on different systems but I have them defined in `.bashrc` as environment variables. I tried to use the env variable `MY_PATH` in the directory config setting but that does not seem to work.

```
[[[terminal20]]]
      directory = $MY_PATH
      order = 0
      parent = child19
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
```

`terminator -l my_layout --working-directory=$MY_PATH` works but starts only terminal 1 on `$MY_PATH` and the other terminals start on `~/home/$USER/`. I don't know how to apply the working directory to all terminals of my_layout.

Any ideas on how to fix it or alternatives?

Thanks!